# Variable formData no reconocida (JQ-AJAX sweetAlert2);

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, sweetalert2

**Planteamiento:** Estoy intentando precargar una imágen desde un botón e insertarla en mysql y una carpeta del proyecto usando sweetAlert2, php puro y jquery.

**Descripción:** La idea es cargar una imagen usando input file de sweetAlert, mostrar la imagen en un modal de pre-carga y si desea cargarla entonces la envié a una carpeta y se inserte en la bd.

**Problema:** Intento la pre-carga en un modal usando FileReader() pero al momento de cargar, php me devuelve el error que dejaré en el código (no recibe la imagen('fileToUpload')).

Comentario: "Sí se envía la foto sin el modal de precarga, se realiza el insert y guarda la imagen en carpeta. Entonces surge el problema, ya que necesito enviar desde el modal de pre-carga:

`const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (e) => {
Swal.fire({Swal.fire({....`

y **no** desde el modal del input file del aSweet"
`const { value: file } = await Swal.fire({....`
 //Editado

Agradezco la ayuda.

```
$('#upload').click(async function() {   
            const { value: file } = await Swal.fire({
                width:280,
                title: 'Select image',
                input: 'file',

            });
            if (file) {
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = (e) => {
                    Swal.fire({
                        width:200,
                        text: 'Your uploaded picture',
                        imageUrl: e.target.result,
                        showCancelButton:true,
                        confirmButtonText:'Cargar',
                        cancelButtonText:'Cancelar',
                        customClass:{
                            confirmButton:'btn btn-success',
                            cancelButton:'btn btn-danger',
                       },
                       buttonsStyling:false,
                  }).then((file)=>{ 
                    if (file.value) {
                        //idea: Al aceptar realice la petición y ejecute insert y envio de la imagen a la carpeta img(Debe ser desde la precarga y no desde el input file)
                        let formData = new FormData();
                        let file = $('.swal2-file')[0].files[0];//Esta clase es asignada por sAlert (la uso para obtener la imangen)
                        formData.append("fileToUpload",file);

                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'uploadPhoto.php',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: formData,
                            processData:false,
                            contentType:false,
                        }).done(function(response) {
                            let photo = response;
                            console.log(response);
                        });
                    }
                });
            },
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    });
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    include 'conexion.php';

    $name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
    $type = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'];
    $size = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'];
    $tmp = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
    $upload = "customersPhoto/".$name;
        move_uploaded_file($tmp, "customersPhoto/".$name);


        $insert = mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO fotos(foto)VALUES('$upload')");
        if (!$insert) {
            echo "fallo la inserccion".$insert;
        }

?>
```

**Botón HTML:**

```
<button id="upload">cargar</button>
```

**ERROR DEVUELTO PHP:**

```
<br/>
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: fileToUpload in ........<b><br />
<br/>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema entonces? Tu *Comentario* me dejó confundido.

Comment: @A.Cedano Edite el comentario. Necesito enviar desde el modal de pre-carga y no desde el modal del input file (de sweetAlert), que es lo que intento.